# Display Name instead of ID inside list manager Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working with oracle APEX to create an application.
I have encountered a problem where I can not show the name instead of the ID inside oracle apex.

Situation is as below

[image]

Is there a way to display the name and have the actual value hide in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the display value followed by the return value.
SOmething like this:

Select name||' '||lname d,
       id r
from table

Comment: The value are auto fetch from database not from query. Any other suggest?